# Does the memory allocated by malloc have boundary？

Tags: c, malloc

here is my code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    void *p=malloc(1);
    int *x=(int*)(p);
    *(x+1000)=1000;
    printf("*(x+1000)=%d\n",*(x+1000));

    //*(x-100)=-100;
    //Segmentation fault

    return 0;
}
```

the output is

```
*(x+1000)=1000
```

but I didn't allocated a memory with 4000(1000*sizeof(int)) sizes memory, only 1.
when I use `*(x-100)=-100`,the shell will output `Segmentation fault`, which seems to make sense.

Can you tell me why?
Thanks
I use ubuntu 16.04.4 and gcc 5.4.0

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing in the C language that prevents you from reading or writing outside the bounds of a variable or allocated memory.

You dynamically allocate 1 byte of memory, then you attempt to write to a memory location 1000 * sizeof(int) bytes after it.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).